# React Native States

Tags: react-native, state

I declare a state at the constructor and try to call it from `renderScene` but `this.state` is always `null` What is wrong?

My code is;

```
var _ = require('underscore');
class ReactNotes extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedNote: { title: "", body: "" },
      notes: {
        1: { title: "Note 1", body: "body", id: 1 },
        2: { title: "Note 2", body: "body", id: 2 }
      }
    };
  } 
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator initialRoute={{ name: 'home' }}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        navigationBar=
        {
          <Navigator.NavigationBar
            routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
            style={styles.navBar}
          />
        }
      />);
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.name) {
      case 'home':
        return (
          <HomeScreen navigator={navigator} notes={_(this.state.notes).toArray()} onSelectNote={(note) => navigator.push({ name: "createNote", note: note })} />
        );
      case 'createNote':
        return (
          <NoteScreen note={this.state.selectedNote}
            onChangeNote={(note) => this.updateNote(note)} />
        );
    }
  }
}
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Looks like binding problem, try: `renderScene={()=>this.renderScene()}`

Comment: Thank u it works:)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your function with arrow function

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
  //...
}
//then call your function in your navigator as  
renderScene={this.renderScene}
```

or

```
// You can use bind() to preserve `this`
renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}>

// Or you can use arrow function this way
renderScene={() => this.renderScene()}>
```

Comment: Thank u, i was mad with this problem, i will never forget arrow:))